# Ajax load page + JQuery click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Why does my ajax not work?

These are my pages.

I'm using JQuery to check click event and using ajax to load the responder page.

What is wrong in this code?

**index.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#clicket').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'res.php?rand=' + Math.random(),
              type: 'GET'
              success: function(results) {
                alert(results);
              }
            });
          });
        });
      </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <button id="clicket">Hi</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Responder page:**

res.php:

```
<?php
  echo "Worked!";
?>
```

**UPDATE:**
I changed my javascript code above.

Comment: You're binding is in the head before the markup is defined; and it isn't in a document ready.  So the selector will not find any elements to bind upon as the DOM has not been fully built yet.

Comment: You forgot to wrap your jQuery code in the document's ready event: `$(function () { ... });`  Conversely, you can put your jQuery code at the end of the HTML instead of the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your logic in a document ready.  Since your script is in your head, the markup in the body hasn't been loaded into the DOM yet.  In order to make your script wait until the DOM has been built, put the logic in a document ready to delay it until that time.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#clicket').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'res.php?rand=' + Math.random(),
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(results) {
        alert(results);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Its amazing how people forgot this simple addition, when almost every jquery example has it :(

Comment: Well, while it is simple, it's also helpful to know why you should use a document ready.  If you know that, then you also know the cases when it is not necessary.

Comment: I used same that u show but does't work again.

Comment: Yes, ...updated.

Comment: Yes man it worked now. I'll mark as answer.

Answer (score -3):

Try using full URL for your ajax call. If you are on live server then write your full domain name, like `www.your_domain.com/res.php?rand=`.

Comment: and put your code into document.ready();

Comment: Nothing wrong with using relative url paths

Comment: best practice to include your javascript code is to embed your javascript code before the </body> closing tag.